# TypeError: 'Sequential' object is not subscriptable when using the model to predict something

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, openai-gym

i've tried to create a model and a function that plays one step in reinforcement learning in lunar lander.

```
import gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
```

this is the environment

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

n_inputs = env.observation_space.shape[0]
n_outputs = env.action_space.n

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", input_shape=[n_inputs]),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation="softmax"),
])
```

this is the model.

```
def lander_play_one_step(env,model, obs, loss_fn):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       probas = model(obs[np.newaxis])
       logits = tf.math.log(probas + keras.backend.epsilon())
       action = (tf.random.categorical(logits, num_samples=1))
       loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_fn(action, probas))

   grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
   obs, reward, done, info = env.step(int(action[0,0].numpy()))
   return obs, reward, done , info




def play_multiple_episodes(env, n_episodes, n_max_steps, model, loss_fn):
    all_rewards = []
    all_grads = []
    for episode in range(n_episodes):
        current_rewards = []
        current_grads = []
        obs = env.reset()
        for step in range(n_max_steps):
            obs, reward, done, grads = lander_play_one_step(env, obs, model, loss_fn)
            current_rewards.append(reward)
            current_grads.append(grads)
        
            if done:
               break
    
        all_rewards.append(current_rewards)
        all_grads.append(current_grads)
    
   return all_rewards, all_grads
```

the error raised up when i ran this loop :

```
n_iteration = 200
n_episodes_per_update = 10 
n_max_steps = 100
discount_factor = 0.9

loss_fn = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)


for iteration in range(n_iteration):
    all_rewards, all_grads = play_multiple_episodes(env, n_episodes_per_update, n_max_steps , model, loss_fn )
    all_final_rewards = discount_and_normalize_rewards(all_rewards, discount_factor)
    
    all_mean_grads = []
    for var_index in range(len(model.trainable_variables)):
        mean_grads = tf.reduce_mean( [final_reward * all_grads[episode_index][step][var_index] 
                                      for episode_index, final_rewards in enumerate(all_final_rewards)
                                            for step , final_reward in enumerate(final_reward)], axis=0 )
        
        all_mean_grads.append(mean_grads)
    
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(all_mean_grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

the error was pointing towards the play_multiple_episodes function, saying it cannot perform lander_play_one_step function because of this line:

```
----> 7         probas = model(obs[np.newaxis])
```

the error : `TypeError: 'Sequential' object is not subscriptable`

here is the full error trace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

      9 
     10 for iteration in range(n_iteration):
---> 11     all_rewards, all_grads = play_multiple_episodes(env, n_episodes_per_update, n_max_steps , model, loss_fn )
     12     all_final_rewards = discount_and_normalize_rewards(all_rewards, discount_factor)
     13 

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11804/128148.py in play_multiple_episodes(env, n_episodes, n_max_steps, model, loss_fn)
     27         obs = env.reset()
     28         for step in range(n_max_steps):
---> 29             obs, reward, done, grads = lander_play_one_step(env, obs, model, loss_fn)
     30             current_rewards.append(reward)
     31             current_grads.append(grads)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11804/128148.py in lander_play_one_step(env, model, obs, loss_fn)
      5 def lander_play_one_step(env,model, obs, loss_fn):
      6     with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
----> 7         probas = model(obs[np.newaxis])
      8         logits = tf.math.log(probas + keras.backend.epsilon())
      9         action = (tf.random.categorical(logits, num_samples=1))

TypeError: 'Sequential' object is not subscriptable
```

Where does the error come from and how can I fix it?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the full error trace (as text) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Hey, i just added the error trace